# Generative network understanding

Tags: keras, gan, hyperparameter, generative-models, parameter

I was going through GAN's notebook by [fchallot](https://github.com/fchollet) on [Generative Adversarial Networks](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/8.5-introduction-to-gans.ipynb) where, in the *Generator Network*, he creates a `Dense` layer with $16*16 * 128$ (where 128 is the number of channels).

- How exactly does `latent_dim=32`  becomes of shape $16 * 16$ in the network.
- How are these values decided?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- latent_dim does not become of shape 16*16

```
x = layers.Dense(128 * 16 * 16)(generator_input)
```

mean: The input of size 32 (the latent_dim) is connected to a layer of size 16*16*128

- These value are decided by the data scientist, they are the hyper-parameters.
  There is a lot of research on how to adjust hyper-parameters for GAN.
  People use generally a size of 100 for the latent_dim but it may depends of the complexity of the image you are trying to generate.